# Is it possible to bind HSI values on input to convert them to RGB?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

The problem is that the conversion from HSI to RGB space does not take into account the entered values, you can set for example H = 0, S = 1 and I = 1, the values obtained after the conversion will be incorrect, because the entered HSI values are incorrect, they must be 0, 1, 0.33. By changing Hue, only Intensity will change from these values, since Saturation is 1. For example, H = 0, S = 1, I = 0.33, then H = 60, S = 1, I = 0.67, and 120 should return to initial state 0.33 H = 120, S = 1, I = 0.33.
If, on top of everything else, change Saturation, then Intensity should also change, for example, H = 0, S = 1, I = 0.33 -> H = 0, S = 0.5, I = 0.5. Also Saturation and Intensity changes with Hue, for example H = 0, S = 0.5, I = 0.5 -> H = 60, S = 0.6, I = 0.75.
By changing Hue to 120 Saturation and Intensity will return to their original values H = 120, S = 0.5, I = 0.5 and so on in a circle up to 360!
Is it possible to bind all three values when they change?

I am working with blueprints in UE4.
Tried linking all values using Map Range Clamped.